# Scaling up using ISO page sizes

Tags: resize, scale, digital-printing, maps, autocad

I have an A3 document with a map that is at a 1:1000 scale (its the only one I have).

How would I scale it down to 1:500 to print on an A1?, because that is the outcome I want an 1:500 scale of the size map on an A1

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software are you using? What format is the document in? Also note that you would have to scale the image up, not down. A1 is four times larger than A3, ie. twice as high, and twice as wide, so I think this would result in the correct scale you require.